# How to prevent a Unity compilation error when using Jenkins and Plastic SCM

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, plasticscm

So we are trying to add in CI to our product development and are having an issue with Plastic, Unity and Jenkins. The error we are seeing is:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Some_Input_Sources' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

The main issue here is when we get the project using the Plastic SCM UI and open in Unity it works fine (no compilation errors, it builds and runs as expected), but when the source is retrieved using Jenkins and the build is attempted it throws that compilation error.

I even attempted to open the project that Jenkins gets manually and it too shows the error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Really depends where `Some_Input_Sources` comes from. Is it your code? Is it a plugin? Is it a package? Are you setting the build target properly?

Comment: Jenkins? Do people still use that thing?  The problem with Jenkins is that it insists on wanting to do things its own way which generally leads to problems compiling a straight up C# class library let alone something more sophisticated as Unity.

Comment: ...consider using _DevOps_ instead.  It's free.   There's even a free Unity build addin in the Marketplace.

Comment: We have no problems at all with Jenkins. It does what you ask it to. We build all of our Unity games, asset bundles, addressables, upload them to the CDN, TestFlight, Google Play, etc.

Comment: Jenkins is a dinosaur....with feathers.